# How to set point in highcharts when x axis and y axis has data as text values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts

I have data like this
`x axis = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']` and
`y axis = ["Aged 1-12", "Aged 13-20 years", "Aged 21-30 years"]`

Now, I want to point x axis with y axis and I am not sure what kind of data format I should enter in data field of Highchart.

I have tried with this input data `[1,2,3,4,5]` but it shows wrong point on chart. Here is graph I have tried with data

[image]

Here is code I have written :

```
Highcharts.chart("c5312209", {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
    text: "Z test"
  },
  tooltip:{
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
      formatter: function(){
        var d = {"1":"Aged Under 10 Years Old","2":"Aged 11-15 Years Old","3":"Aged 16-17 Years Old","13":"Aged Over 101 Years Old"};
        return d[this.value];
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    title: {
      text: 'Time'
    }
  },
  series: [{data: [0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]
});
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have one point for each month, then giving data as you have done `series: [{data: [0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]` is a good option. If you want to set points only for some months you can explicitly state the x value like this: `series: [{data: [{x:0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 13}...]}]`. In your config there was an issue with the formatter (y ticks are getting placed at the wrong values compared to the labels), here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/me9pyzqv/14/

Comment: thank you @ewolden for quick reply. I am going to try with your solution.

Comment: @ewolden is it possible to show data without series e.g. no text `series 1` ?

Comment: Yes, depending on what you want you can either do: `series: [{name: '', ...}]` which will set the name to nothing. Or `series: [{`[`showInLegend`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.showInLegend)`: false,...}]` which will remove the series from the legend.

Comment: @ewolden it works. Thank you... Please add you comment on answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one point for each month, then giving data as you have done `series: [{data: [0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]` is a good option.

If you want to set points only for some months you can explicitly state the x value like this:

```
series: [{data: [{x:0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 13}...]}]
```

In your config there was an issue with the formatter (y ticks are getting placed at the wrong values compared to the labels), here is a **working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/me9pyzqv/14

---

From the comment, to hide a series from the legend, or remove the series name, the following can be done:

You can either do: `series: [{name: '', ...}]` which will set the name to nothing. Or `series: [{showInLegend: false,...}]` which will remove the series from the legend.

Comment: Hi @ewolden can you please help me to that what data format I should enter to show line chart day wise ? I have tried this
```
    series: [{
      showInLegend:false, 
      data: [
        [(new Date("Mon, 26 Feb 2018 13:43:00 UTC +00:00").getTime()), 12],
        [(new Date("Mon, 19 Feb 2018 16:00:00 UTC +00:00").getTime()), 2],
        [(new Date("Sat, 13 Jan 2018 11:00:00 UTC +00:00").getTime()), 3],
        [(new Date("Fri, 20 Feb 2009 00:00:00 UTC +00:00").getTime()), 0] 
      ] 
    }]
```

Comment: I have tried to enter data in given format but show wrong label but point tool tip shows correct date https://jsfiddle.net/me9pyzqv/17/

Comment: as problem is related to same as question, I would rather to just add comment. I have updated your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/me9pyzqv/21/

Comment: Okay. I think I find the solution. Thank you so much for your help. If anything stops me I will ask new question.